# How to make python ignore square bracket?

Tags: video, video-editor

I have a code it work with fine with with file name does not contain square bracket []

an example:
**10245,13445.avi**

```
def insert_types(out, dir):
for root, dirs, files in walk(dir):
   for f in os.listdir(dir):
        match =  search(r"(\d+),(\d+)\.avi$", f)
        if match:
            startframe = match.group(1)
            endframe = match.group(2)
            out = fvf.InsertSign(out, join(root, f), int(startframe), int(endframe), matrix="709")
return out
```

This code works with `.avi` file format and it take the first and the second values with the comma mark `,`  and its only work with the filename which does not contain square bracket like  `10245,13445.avi`
But now I want to make this code ignore the square bracket [] in file name `[10245,13445].avi`  how it gonna be, any help?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regex pattern should be

```
search(r"(\d+),(\d+)\]*\.avi$", f)
```

previously, the pattern is "13445" + ".avi"
now, the pattern is "13445" + "]" + ".avi", and it should be fine with or without square brackets.